# How to use const inside modules?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
mod delicious_snacks {
    use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit;
    use self::veggies::CUCUMBER as veggie;

    mod fruits {
        pub const PEAR: &'static str = "Pear";
        pub const APPLE: &'static str = "Apple";
    }

    mod veggies {
        pub const CUCUMBER: &'static str = "Cucumber";
        pub const CARROT: &'static str = "Carrot";
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "favorite snacks: {} and {}",
            delicious_snacks::fruit,
            delicious_snacks::veggie
    );
}
```

I'm getting an error that fruit and veggie [are private](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=502fcbbca86129646e9443544266c592) when I try to print them:

```
error[E0603]: constant `fruit` is private
  --> src/main.rs:19:31
   |
19 |             delicious_snacks::fruit,
   |                               ^^^^^

error[E0603]: constant `veggie` is private
  --> src/main.rs:20:31
   |
20 |             delicious_snacks::veggie
   |                               ^^^^^^
```

Can any one explain me this and help me resolve?

Comment: source : https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/modules/modules2.rs

Comment: BTW, since Rust implements [`'static` lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#static-lifetime-elision), you can have just `pub const PEAR: &str = "Pear";` etc..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The accessibility of an item defined with `use` is independent from the accessibility of the used item. This means that while `PEAR` is public, `use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit;` is private. You must export those items publicly:

```
pub use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit;
pub use self::veggies::CUCUMBER as veggie;
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e24e25ef5b64972bf3fb95fafa29006b))

Comment: Thank's for very clear and to the point explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It means it is only visible from the `delicious_snacks` module.

To use `delicious_snacks::fruit` and the other constants,  they need to be exported publicly from the module using the `pub` modifier:

```
mod delicious_snacks {
    pub use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit;
    pub use self::veggies::CUCUMBER as veggie;
```

Answer (score -1):

To use

```rust
pub mod fruits {
```

and

```rust
println!(
        "favorite snacks: {}",
        delicious_snacks::fruits::PEAR,
);
```

is another way to address problem